# Can't create user home in /mnt

Tags: users, home-directory

I want to create a user home in `/mnt` with `useradd` but it didn't create it.

```
useradd user -d /mnt/home/user -s /bin/shell
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I'm root and I'm using sudo too, and it didn't works @Terrance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man useradd`:

```
       -d, --home-dir HOME_DIR
           The new user will be created using HOME_DIR as the value for the
           user's login directory. The default is to append the LOGIN name to
           BASE_DIR and use that as the login directory name. The directory
           HOME_DIR does not have to exist but will not be created if it is
           missing.
```

You can either create the directory manually, or add the `-m` (`--create-directory`) option:

```
       -m, --create-home
           Create the user's home directory if it does not exist. The files
           and directories contained in the skeleton directory (which can be
           defined with the -k option) will be copied to the home directory.

           By default, if this option is not specified and CREATE_HOME is not
           enabled, no home directories are created.
```